# how use multipleClass jQuery click event

Tags: jquery, css

i want one .heading click .collpase is active , remove and slideup and slide down  but all collpase active how use jquery... i am tired , how use one click and one class active

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapmenu .heading').on('click', function(){
        $('.wrapmenu .collpase').addClass('acitve');
    });
});
```

///html

```
   <div class="heading">Transmission <span><i class="icon-caret-down"></i></div>
   <div class="collapse">
      <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Automatic <span>(10)</span> </label></div>
     <div class="more-option">Show More Options <span><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="wrapmenu unicode ieUnicode">

   <div class="heading">Transmission <span><i class="icon-caret-down"></i></div>
   <div class="collapse">
      <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Automatic <span>(10)</span> </label></div>
     <div class="more-option">Show More Options <span><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

///css

```
.wrapmenu {
border:1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
cursor:pointer;
}
.wrapmenu .heading {
background-color:#F5F5F5;
padding:10px;
position:relative;
}
.wrapmenu .heading  span{
float:right;
}
.wrapmenu .collapse{
background-color:#fff;
padding:10px;
border-top:1px solid #ddd;
}
.active{display:block;}
```

Comment: You have a typo `acitve`

Comment: i wnat addClass and removeClass after SlideDown and SlideUp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `$(this)` reference inside the click event handler, and target the element with class collapse by using the `.next()` function, since it is the immediately next sibling to the current element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapmenu .heading').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('.collapse').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: how use slidedown solowly speed collpase class

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

Here `$(this)` will gives you current clicked element and `.next('.collpase')` give you the next element which has `class=collpase`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapmenu .heading').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('.collpase').addClass('acitve');
    });
});
```

**Note** : your active class spelling should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is getting all the classes `.collapse`

For specific class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapmenu .heading').on('click', function(){
        $(this).siblings('.collapse').toggleClass('active').slideToggle(1000);


    });
});
```

`siblings()`, here, would work if you have only one class `.collapse`.

If you have many `.collapse` in the same parent, use `.next()` as suggested by Rajaprabhu.

Comment: tanks my friends but i up vote not work up vote. i have no marks 15marks. so i not give up vote sorry....

Comment: how use slidedown and slideup myfriends

Comment: you cant, you need 15+ reputation to Vote up